# Maybe you haven't applied enough arguments to a function?

Tags: haskell

I am learning Haskell in a course in university, and there is a Exam-Exercise, where we need to define a function which takes a List of functions  `[(Int ->Int)]` and another parameter of Type `Int` and returns an `Int`. So the Type should be

```
compose :: [(Int ->Int)] -> Int -> Int.
```

The function should return a composition of the functions in the list from left to right and apply it to the 2nd parameter.
I tried the following :

```
compose :: [(Int -> Int)] -> Int -> Int
compose [] x = x
compose (f:fs) x  
    |fs == [] = f x
    |f  : (compose fs x)
```

But the compiler throws an error :

```
003Exam.hs:24:22:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘[Int -> Int]’
    In the expression: f : (compose fs x)
    In an equation for ‘compose’:
        compose (f : fs) x
          | fs == [] = f x
          | otherwise = f : (compose fs x)

003Exam.hs:24:28:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[Int -> Int]’ with actual type ‘Int’
    In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘(compose fs x)’
    In the expression: f : (compose fs x)
```

If I leave the last line away, like :

```
compose :: [(Int -> Int)] -> Int -> Int
compose [] x = x
compose (f:fs) x  
    |fs == [] = f x
```

then I also get an error - this is the one that I realy don't understand :

```
003Exam.hs:23:13:
    No instance for (Eq (Int -> Int))
      (maybe you haven't applied enough arguments to a function?)
      arising from a use of ‘==’
    In the expression: fs == []
    In a stmt of a pattern guard for
               an equation for ‘compose’:
      fs == []
    In an equation for ‘compose’: compose (f : fs) x | fs == [] = f x
```

I would be happy for any help that clarifies what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, `(:)` is only for adding elements at the front of a list (or pattern match against those), so you have to replace

```
f : compose fs x
```

with

```
f (compose fs x)
```

Next, you have to use an expression of type `Bool` or a pattern match in a guard:

```
| fs == []  = -- this line is still wrong, see below
| otherwise = f (compose f xs)
```

However, there is no `Eq` instance for functions. The equivalence of two functions is undecidable (in general), so use `null :: [a] -> Bool` instead of `(==) :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool`:

```
compose :: [(Int -> Int)] -> Int -> Int
compose [] x = x
compose (f:fs) x  
  | null fs   = f x
  | otherwise = f (compose fs x)
```

Since `compose [] x` is the same as `x` you can even remove the check:

```
compose :: [(Int -> Int)] -> Int -> Int
compose []     x = x
compose (f:fs) x = f (compose fs x)
```

#### Exercises

- Extend `compose [(+1), (+2)] 1` (replace it with its definition) without getting rid of intermediate terms. Do you notice a pattern?
- Does this pattern remind you of a library function?
- Try to use that library function in order to write `compose`.

Comment: wow, thank you all very much. I just had some spaghetti, and when I came back here there are so many qualitative answers. Now I believe that I understand what the problem is/ was. Thank you. ( I guess you mean fold ?) :D. Thank you all

Comment: @DavidJambalaya You're welcome. Note that [you want to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others know that you're question has been answered. You can change the accepted answer at any time. Aaaaaaand I just noticed an error in my answer. And yes, it's a fold. Not going to tell you which one, though :D.

Comment: What do you mean "which fold"? `foldMap` will certainly do it regardless!

Comment: @dfeuer `foldMap Endo` is a neat trick; / for newcomers it's dark magic. / With `fold*` you're almost on par / if you replace `*` by `l` or `r`.

Comment: At least until the default books use post FTP material.

Comment: @Zeta, see my answer for a way that goes a bit beyond :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
|f  : (compose fs x)
    ^
```

I think your problem is that this colon shouldn't be here.
`:` in Haskell is the list constructor which is why the compiler is telling you that you are trying to return an `[Int -> Int]`. If it wasn't there, f would simply be applied and you'd be returning an `Int`.

Comment: there is another problem with `fs == []` and "No instance for (Eq (Int -> Int))"

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply the functions on the result repeatedly, and empty function list should be treated as id.

```
Prelude> let comp :: [(Int->Int)] -> Int -> Int
Prelude|     comp [] x = x
Prelude|     comp (f:fs) x = comp fs (f x)
Prelude|
Prelude> comp [(^2),(+1)] 3
10
```

I read the problem wrong, above is applying functions from left to right.  If you're composing from left to right (rightmost function will be applied first) it should be like this (now point-free)

```
Prelude> let comp2 :: [(Int->Int)] -> Int -> Int
Prelude|     comp2 [] = id
Prelude|     comp2 (f:fs) = f . comp2 fs
Prelude|
Prelude> comp2 [(^2),(+1)] 3
16
Prelude> comp2 [negate,(+2)] 3
-5
```

Comment: This changes the semantics of the original function, since `comp [negate, (+2)] 3` is `-5` in the question, but `-1` in your variant.

Answer (score 1):

Since its been a few hours, let me offer a couple hints about writing this as a fold. Since there are two directions you can compose the functions, and I don't get any points for doing it the right way, I'll just show both.

First, some boilerplate:

```
import Data.Monoid (Dual (..))
import Control.Category (Category (..))
import Data.Foldable (Foldable (foldMap))
import Prelude hiding (id, (.))
```

Next, a type explaining that a monoid is a category with exactly one object:

```
newtype Cat c a = Cat { getCat :: c a a }

instance Category c => Monoid (Cat c a) where
  mempty = Cat id
  mappend (Cat f) (Cat g) = Cat (f . g)
```

Finally, the functions you seek, generalized from `->` to an arbitrary `Category`:

```
compose1 :: (Foldable f, Category c) => f (c a a) -> c a a
compose1 = getCat . foldMap Cat

compose2 :: (Foldable f, Category c) => f (c a a) -> c a a
compose2 = getCat . getDual . foldMap (Dual . Cat)
```

Exercise for the reader: write the equivalent functions replacing `Category` with `Semigroupoid` and `Foldable` with `Foldable1`.

Another exercise for the reader: write the `Monoid (Cat c a)` instance using `Data.Coerce.coerce` and/or `#.` and `.#` from `Data.Profunctor.Unsafe` to avoid spurious closure allocation.

---

P.S. The `Cat` type only explains half the story. Here's the rest:

```
newtype Mon m a b = Mon m

instance Monoid m => Category (Mon m) where
  id = Mon mempty
  Mon m . Mon n = Mon (m `mappend` n)
```

It would arguably be more precise to use

```
data Mon m a b where
  Mon :: m -> Mon m a a
```

But this would be less efficient without really adding much value.

Comment: *Your answer is quite off the hook, / though it's a shame for the time it took. / Please don't see this as critique / but your this answer is off topic.* I'm not sure how far they go [in David's lecture](https://www.uni-bamberg.de/?id=24762), but given the syntactical errors, I don't think they handled `Foldable` or `Monoid`. Also given that you don't answer the original question you're using an orbital cannon to shoot a tree but slightly miss it. After  all, `compose1 = foldr (.) id` and `compose2 = foldr (flip (.)) id` (with `Control.Category`).

Comment: Well, not 100% off-topic, you provide a working `compose`, but you get what I mean (and the rhyme on "critique" was really nice; have no idea why I'm rhyming lately, though).

Comment: @Zeta, that's not quite true, since an infinite snoc list, say, may give a result in some categories using my code, but never using `foldr`.

Comment: Sure, probably should have added " in the context of this question". For "How can I fold endomorphisms in a `Foldable` into a single one", your answer is pretty much spot on. (Don't you need to sleep once in a while?)

Comment: @Zeta, I try, but I'm not very good at going to bed at sensible hours.